# Simple haskell program doesnt compile with GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

Consider what follows to be my code

```
 import Data.Char
 import Data.List

-- square
square :: Int -> Int
square n = n * n
```

Although this square functions looks neat and clear, when I run it

```
ghci ./square.hs
```

It returns

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ./LabSheet1-solns.hs, interpreted )

./LabSheet1-solns.hs:5:1:
    parse error on input `square'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

There should probably be something wrong with my interpreter.

I am running on OS X 10.8.1

```
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.2
```

Any clue?

Comment: Assuming the imports are correctly indented in your actual code file, this compiles just fine for me.

Comment: @JaniHartikainen Why would you assume that when the code as given produces exactly the error message the OP says it does?

Comment: @sepp2k because of the inability of so many people to use the SO post editor correctly. That's why it was a comment and not an answer, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `import` statements are indented by one space. This basically sets "one space" as the base indentation level for the file. Since your definition of `square` is not indented by one space, you get a syntax error.

To fix the problem, either indent all lines by one space, or preferably don't indent the `import` statements.

Answer (score 5):

Fix your indentation:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

-- square
square :: Int -> Int
square n = n * n
```